# Call azure function behind private endpoint in release gate

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

We have an endpoint on our function app that returns the status of any in progress durable functions.

We want to use this endpoint as a release gate to avoid deploying while there's any in flight orchestrations - however the app is behind a private endpoint in azure.

The release gates don't seem to run on the agent and so can't hit the endpoint. Is there a way around this?